# Enforce <Input type="email" Pattern > for Safari Browser

Tags: html, forms, validation, safari

```
<input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" class="text" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="ON" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
```

I have the above in an HTML form I am working on. I would like to enforce email validation such that a user would have to input an entry with a valid email format. I understand that this is only browser authentication and would like to learn this before i proceed. It works fine on Chrome but not on Safari for Windows. When I enter "abc." in the email field on a Safari browser, it accepts it. Chrome prompts you to correct the entry.

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working on Safari?

Comment: what you are doing right now is relying on the `HTML5 required` attribute which does the error checking for the `type='email'`. I'm not sure why it isn't working in Safari, I didn't test it, but I prefer to do my own error checking using `JavaScript` / `jQuery`. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Note that Safari on Windows is a very old browser - Apple pretty much stopped development at v5.1, back in early 2012 (compared with current version 8 on Mac).

This means that it is missing loads of features, and has many outstanding bugs.

In fact, it's not even easy to download the Windows version any more -- Apple basically doesn't support it any more at all, and virtually nobody is actually using it.

In short, there's very little point in even trying to test for Safari on Windows. Test the Mac version, for sure, but don't bother with the Windows version.